# Same user in different processes

Tags: process, bpmn, camunda-modeler

I’m a bpmn newbie with a pretty complicated process to model.

Does it make sense to have the same user (`user 1` in my case) in different processes?
And how can I link `process 2` and `process 3`, since `process 2` has two different ends?

[image: Draft_process]

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of a *lane* in a *pool* is left to the modeler, so you. There can perfectly be two lanes in two different pools, that share the same user name. Note that the lane name is free and does not formally define the *performer* of the *tasks* in the model (even if visually the meaning is clear).

If you need to link `process 2` and `process 3` with a message flow the simplest way would be to either issue two message flows or merge the two ends (if the flow ends, it ends, regardless of the user).

**Important remark**:  an end event symbol on a process should in principe not have outgoing flows.  If you want to connect the process with a message flow like you did between 1 and 2, the end event should me a *message end event* (thick circle with envelope in it). And the consequence would be that the receiving process starts with a *message start event* (thin circle with an envelope in it). If there is no message between the two,  don't link them.